# What are my options to log into an app with an API key?

Tags: android, authentication, api-key

I have an Android app, where the login is a bit weird: first, you have to register somewhere else. After that, you have to open the app, tap on the login button, receive an email and if you tap on the link, it switches to the app and logs in.
Now, I reinstalled my phone, and this doesn't work anymore, the link opens the app, but does not log me in, it acts like nothing happened. I've wrote to the support, "they will investigate"...

I would like to solve the problem by myself, though I'm not an Android developer (I am not a developer, but I have some programming experience). I suspect the link contains the API key generated for me, but after that I don't know what happens inside the app's code. What do you think, what could I do? Modify the app? Write some kind of program for it?

Thank you for your answers!

I took a look in the application, I've downloaded the apk, opened in Android Studio, searched for term "api"  but I have no idea where and what should I find.

Comment: It's unlikely anyone will be able to help you with this.  The original link you got likely contained a code of some sort that the app saw and saved.  If you still have that link it may work but probably not - the link may be a one time use link.  I'm afraid you'll likely have to wait for the app vendor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.